# How to create collection without database in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

How can I add items to my list `SearchedVideos`?
I would like to have these items on the list until the end of my application.
Now I have error like this:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I create **context** with prop as **Singleton** like this:

```
public List<QueryViewModel> SearchedVideos { get; set; }
```

In **startup**

```
services.AddSingleton<YtContext>();
```

My **model**

```
public class ExecutedQuery
{
    public Query Query { get; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Video> Videos { get; set; }

    public ExecutedQuery(Query query, string title, IReadOnlyList<Video> videos)
    {
        Query = query;
        Title = title;
        Videos = videos;
    }
}
```

My **service**

```
public async Task<ExecutedQuery> ExecuteQueryAsync(Query query)
    {
        // Search
        if (query.Type == QueryType.Search)
        {
            var videos = await _youtubeClient.SearchVideosAsync(query.Value);
            var title = $"Search: {query.Value}";

            var executedQueries = new ExecutedQuery(query, title, videos);

            var qw = new QueryViewModel
            {
                ExecutedQueries = executedQueries,
            };

            _ytcontext.SearchedVideos.Add(qw);

            return executedQueries;
        }
    }
```

My **QueryViewModel**

```
public ExecutedQuery ExecutedQueries { get; set; }
```

My **Controller**

```
[HttpGet("Search/all")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListAllQueriesAsync(string query)
    {
        var req = _queryService.ParseQuery(query);
        var res = await _queryService.ExecuteQueryAsync(req);

        return View(res);
    }
```

Comment: Need to see some code.  Show your "context", your service, and Controllers

Comment: If you dont need a database then try file handling in c#.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8     By the way that was just a suggestion. Need to see some code...

Comment: Maybe creating a singleton for your "context" would work. This is just for a demo, right? You don't want to persist your changes?

Answer (score 1):

Each request is its own thing, unaffected by anything that's happened before or since. As such, you pretty much start from a blank slate. The typical means for persisting state between one or more additional requests is the session. Sessions are essentially fake state, through a combination of server-side (some persistent store) and client-side components (cookies), something that appears like persistence of state can be achieved. However, particularly on the server-side, you still need some sort of store, which is generally a database of some sort, be it relational (SQL Server, etc.) or NoSQL (Redis, etc.). The default session store will be in-memory, which may suffice for your needs, but as memory is volatile, any sort of app restart will take anything stored there along with it.

Alternatively, there's statics and objects with singleton lifetimes. In either case, they're virtually the same as in-memory storage - they'll persist the life of the application and no more.

Statics are just members with a `static` keyword on them. It's probably the simplest and most straight-forward approach, but also the most fragile. It's virtually impossible to test statics, so you're basically creating black-holes in your code where anything could happen.

A better approach is to simply use an object with a singleton lifetime. These can be create via the `AddSingleton<T>` method on the service collection. For example, you could create a class like:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    public ICollection<IReadOnlyList<Video>> SearchedVideo { get; set; }
}
```

And then register it as a singleton in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<MySingleton>();
```

Then, in your controllers, views, and such, you can inject `MySingleton` to access the `SearchedVideos` property. As a singleton, the data there will persist for the life of the application.

The chief difference between sessions, particularly in-memory sessions, and either statics or singletons is one of breadth. Sessions will always be tied to a particular client, whereas statics and singletons will be scoped to the application. That means that if you use statics or singletons, *all* clients will see the same data and will potentially manipulate the same data. If you need something that is client-specific, you must use sessions, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to edit this list from one instance to another then you'll need to use some kind of datasource.  If a database is not an option then a text file will have to do.  Use a Json string and serialize/deserialize to your object.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data.  I've used this method to mockup an application but if you are going to be doing alot of writing to the file you may run into issues.

If you can hard code the list in the application then a Singleton will work.  Read up here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

@natsukiss i guess you are trying to call **Add()** method from **null property**. Even you create a list you should set an initial instance for **SearchedVideo** Property. Because if you dont create an instance, it means that property will not have address in memory. Because of that sometimes we are using **string TestVal = ""**. That means we sets initial value on **Common Language Runtime(CLR)** to locate Address in Memory.

```
public List<QueryViewModel> SearchedVideos { get; set; } = new List<QueryViewModel>(); //<==
```

or if you are working with EntityFramework you should use

```
public ICollection<QueryViewModel> SearchedVideos { get; set; } = new HashSet<QueryViewModel>(); //<===
```

Comment: Yes, right! Damn.. that mistake...! :) Thanks bro :)

Comment: if you have big project and many async progress belive me that mistake may not seen while on debugging. You should always consider to set initial values. :)